# how to use MVCObject not using load google maps js ,

Tags: javascript, google-maps

all know google has a MVCObject , it isvery useful ,

but i want to use it in my js file , but i want to load full google maps js ,

so what can i do ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://code.google.com/p/mvcobject-js/) standalone version of Google's MVCObject: